# Tire Gem with Ransack for elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire, ransack

I've been using Ransack with my MySQL data to produce an advanced form, I've switched over to elasticsearch recently and now I'm finding that even a simple form doesn't work (using the activerecord functionality within tire)

A simple form produces the error 'No valid predicate for x' where x is what I'm searching for..

Searching around, either I'm the only one who has tried this or it works for everyone else?

Am I missing something?

```
 index.html.erb    
   <%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :attendees %>
      <%= f.text_field :attendes %>
      <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>

    <%=  @events.inspect %>

Events controller

def index
    @q = Event.search(params[:q])
    @events = @q.result
end

event.rb

  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks
```

Comment: Can you add/link more of the backtrace?

Answer (score 1):

Ransack search object can't generate Tire search.

There is no adapter for the elastic search, only AR

https://github.com/ernie/ransack/tree/master/lib/ransack/adapters